# AST in search button of eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

i want to know whether AST is used in the implementation of search button in eclipse..any idea ..help

Comment: AST = Abstract Systax Tree?
Maybe you can be a bit more specific in your question and provide some background information. That would make it easier for people to provide good answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "Java Search" of eclipse works with a prebuild index for performance reasons. The index is build with the help of the java parser (and hence with the usage of the AST).